# retryWhen with timer appears to subvert merge behavior

Tags: java-8, rx-java

I'm using RxJava in an asynchronous messaging environment (vert.x), and so have a flow that looks like this:

```
Observable.defer( () -> getEndpoint() )
          .mergeWith( getCancellationMessage() )
          .flatMap( endpoint -> useEndpoint( endpoint ) )
          .retryWhen( obs -> obs.flatMap( error -> {
              if ( wasCancelled( error ) ) {
                  return Observable.error( error );
              }
              return Observable.timer(/* args */)
          }) )
          .subscribe( result -> useResult( result ),
                      error -> handleError( error )
          );
```

The implementation of `getCancellationMessage()` returns an observable stream that emits an error whenever a cancellation message has been received from an independent message source. This stream never emits anything other than `Observable.error()`, and it only emits an error when it receives a cancellation message.

If I understand how `merge` works, the entire chain should be terminated via `onError` when `getCancellationMessage()` emits an error.

However, I am finding that if the `retryWhen` operator is waiting for the timer to emit when a cancellation message is received, the error is ignored and the `retryWhen` loop continues as if the cancellation was never received.

I can fix the behavior by merging `Observable.timer()` with the same `getCancellationMessage()` function, but I'm not understanding why I have to do that in the first place.

Is this `merge`/`retryWhen` interaction expected?

**Edits:**

Below is an example of the kind of thing that the `getCancellationMessage()` function is doing:

```
Observable<T> getCancellationMessage() {
    if ( this.messageStream == null ) {
       this.messageStream = this.messageConsumer.toObservable()
                            .flatMap( message -> {
                                this.messageConsumer.unregister();
                                if ( isCancelMessage(message) ) {
                                    return Observable.error( new CancelError() );
                                }
                                else {
                                    return Observable.error( new FatalError() );
                                }
                            });
    }
    return this.messageStream;
}
```

Note that I don't own the implementation of `this.messageConsumer` - this comes from the third party library I'm using (vert.x), so I don't control the implementation of that Observable.

As I understand it, the `messageConsumer.toObservable()` method returns the result of `Observable.create()` provided with an instance of [this class](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-rx/blob/master/rx-java/src/main/java/io/vertx/lang/rxjava/ReadStreamAdapter.java), which will call the subscriber's `onNext` method whenever a new message [has arrived](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-rx/blob/master/rx-java/src/main/java/io/vertx/lang/rxjava/ReadStreamAdapter.java#L23-L25).

The call to `messageConsumer.unregister()` prevents any further messages from being received.

Comment: Reading documentation, it doesn't mention enywhere that `Observable.timer` calls `onError` at all. And since `onError` is not called by the timer, child subscription doesn't call `onError` either, so it ignores exceptions. Honestly, I sort of lack in-depth knowledge to answer this with confidence, but have you tried what official documentation suggests over [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#retryWhen(rx.functions.Func1))

Comment: I'm not really expecting `Observable.timer()` to produce an error, but while the `timer` is running, it's absolutely true that `getCancellationMessage` has emitted an error, and I'm wondering why it's getting ignored. Even after the timer elapses, it's as if `getCancellationMessage` never issued `Observable.error()`. There isn't anything I've found in the `retryWhen` documentation that would explain what I'm seeing.

Comment: But looking at the graph in url I posted before, if observable from `retryWith` doesn't call `onError`, then resulting observable continues the loop, which sounds like what you're experiencing.

Comment: What's confusing me is that 'continuing the loop' should encounter the merged observable from `getCancellationMessage` at the top of the chain, which did call `onError`. How can that be ignored? Looking at documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html)

Comment: From the `merge` documentation> As shown in the above diagram, an onError notification from any of the source Observables will immediately be passed through to observers and will terminate the merged Observable.

Comment: My guess is that "onError will be passed through to observes and terminate" action takes place before "retryWith" is encountered, and "retry" then swallows the onError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I am finding that if the retryWhen operator is waiting for the timer to emit when a cancellation message is received, the error is ignored and the retryWhen loop continues as if the cancellation was never received.

The operator `retryWhen` turns an upstream `Throwable` into a value and routes it through the sequence you provided in order to get a value response to retry the upstream or end the stream, thus

```
Observable.error(new IOException())
.retryWhen((Observable<Throwable> error) -> error)
.subscribe();
```

Will retry indefinitely because the inner `error` is considered a value now, not an exception.

`retryWhen` doesn't know by itself which of the `error` values should it consider to be one that shouldn't be retried, that's the job of your inner flow:

```
Observable.defer( () -> getEndpoint() )
  .mergeWith( getCancellationMessage() )
  .flatMap( endpoint -> useEndpoint( endpoint ) )
  .retryWhen( obs -> obs
            .takeWhile( error -> !( error instanceof CancellationException ) ) // <-------
            .flatMap( error -> Observable.timer(/* args */) ) 
  )
  .subscribe( result -> useResult( result ),
              error -> handleError( error )
);
```

Here, we only let the error pass if it is not of type `CancellationException` (you can replace it with your error type). This will complete the sequence.

If you want the sequence to end with an error instead, we need to change the `flatMap` logic instead:

```
 .retryWhen(obs -> obs
      .flatMap( error -> {
           if (error instanceof CancellationException) {
               return Observable.error(error);
           }
           return Observable.timer(/* args */);
      })
 )
```

Note that returning `Observable.empty()` in `flatMap` doesn't end the sequence as it just indicates a source to be merged is empty but there could be still other inner sources. In particular to `retryWhen`, an `empty()` will hang the sequence indefinitely because there won't be any signal to indicate retry or end-of-sequence.

**Edit:**

Based on your wording, I assume `getCancellationMessage()` is a hot observable. Hot observables have to be observed in order to receive their events or errors. When the `retryWhen` operator is in its retry grace period due to `timer()`, there is nothing subscribed to the topmost `mergeWith` with the `getCancellationMessage()` and thus it can't stop the timer at that point.

You have to keep a subscription to it while the `timer` executes to stop it right away:

```
Observable<Object> cancel = getCancellationMessage();

Observable.defer( () -> getEndpoint() )
  .mergeWith( cancel )
  .flatMap( endpoint -> useEndpoint( endpoint ) )
  .retryWhen( obs -> obs
      .flatMap( error -> {
           if (error instanceof CancellationException) {
               return Observable.error(error);
           }
           return Observable.timer(/* args */).takeUntil( cancel );
      })
  )
  .subscribe( result -> useResult( result ),
              error -> handleError( error )
);
```

In this case, if `cancel` fires while the timer is executing, the `retryWhen` will stop the timer and terminate with the cancel error immediately.

Using `takeUntil` is one option, as you found out, `mergeWith ( cancel )` again works as well.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation. I'm going to apply your recommendations and verify whether they address this behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to change the behavior. If `retryWhen` has encountered an error that caused it to return `Observable.timer()`, then any errors produced after that point, but before the timer has expired, are ignored. `retryWhen` doesn't even seem to be getting invoked with that later error.

Comment: I updated the sample code accordingly. Still confused.

Comment: How can you emit an error when there is a retryWhen timer going on. That means that there is no subscription to whatever retryWhen's source is. How is getCancellationMessage() implemented? Is it hot, like a PublishSubject?

Comment: `getCancellationMessage()` returns an `Observable` that will call the subscriber's `onNext()` method whenever a new message has arrived. I don't believe that it's hot - it requires a subscriber. Messages can arrive at any time. The scenario I'm looking at has `useEndpoint()` producing an error that should be retried, and while we're waiting to retry, a cancel message is sent, so the `getCancellationMessage()` Observable should emit at that time, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I'll add a sample implementation of `getCancellationMessage()` to the question